# Split large csv file and keep header in each part

Tags: bash, csv, split

How to split a large csv file (~100GB) and preserve the header in each part ?

For instance

```
h1 h2
a  aa
b  bb
```

into

```
h1 h2
a  aa
```

and

```
h1 h2
b  bb
```

Comment: how can we know what is "each part" with such a tiny example?

Comment: This is too broad. Provide a [mcve] together with what you tried.

Comment: Looks like a potential duplicate and there's a better answer (using `awk`) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51420966/split-csv-files-into-smaller-files-but-keeping-the-headers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you need to separate the header and the content :

```
header=$(head -1 $file)
data=$(tail -n +2 $file)
```

Then you want to split the data

```
echo $data | split [options...] -
```

In the options you have to specify the size of the chunks and the pattern for the name of the resulting files. The trailing `-` must not be removed as it specifies `split` to read data from stdin.

Then you can insert the header at the top of each file

```
sed -i "1i$header" $splitOutputFile
```

You should obviously do that last part in a for loop, but its exact code will depend on the prefix chosen for the `split` operation.

Comment: Wouldn't `data=$(tail -n +2 $file)` try to load the entire file into memory?

Comment: @NeilC.Obremski I can't say for sure honestly. Maybe I'll find the time to test it, if you do first please give me your feedback !

Answer (score 1):

I found any previous solutions to this to not work properly on the mac systems that my script was targeting (why Apple? why?) I eventually ended up with a printf option that worked out pretty good as a proof of concept. I'm going to enhance this by putting the temporary files into a ramdisk and the like to improve performance since it is putting a bunch on disk as is and will probably be slow.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Pass a file in as the first argument on the command line (note, not secure)
file=$1

# Get the header file out
header=$(head -1 $file)

# Separate the data from the header
tail -n +2 $file > output.data

# Split the data into 1000 lines per file (change as you wish)
split -l 1000 output.data output

# Append the header back into each file from split 
for part in `ls -1 output*`
do
  printf "%s\n%s" "$header" "`cat $part`" > $part
done
```

Answer (score 0):

you may download a freeware CsvSplitter from [here](https://www.erdconcepts.com/dbtoolbox/csvsplitter/csvsplitter.zip). It is a zip from the website that contains a simple portable .exe file and a .txt file, necessary to work along with the executable, just extract the content in some directory and you're ready to work:

[image]
and it can split the file as can be seen in this picture
[image]

Everything is self-explanatory but more details can be found  [here](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/1154/how-to-split-huge-csv-datasets-into-smaller-files-using-csv-splitter-in-windows-10)