# Split CSV files into smaller files but keeping the headers?

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have a huge CSV file, 1m lines. I was wondering if there is a way to split this file into smaller ones but keeping the first line (CSV header) on all the files.

It seems `split` is very fast but is also very limited.  You cannot add a suffix to the filenames like `.csv`.

```
split -l11000 products.csv file_
```

Is there an effective way to do this task in just `bash`? A one-line command would be great.

Comment: Hmm. I forgot that my gold bash gives me the ability to shut down a question. Didn't really mean for that to happen. I know other readers can still reply. The answer below looks pretty good. Put it in a shell script and then your have you one-liner. Good luck..

Comment: Voting to re-open as the question isn't a duplicate. There is a specific difference in retaining the first line along all the split files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a file and keep the first line in each of the pieces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411713/how-to-split-a-file-and-keep-the-first-line-in-each-of-the-pieces)

Comment: The best tool for this purpose is `xsv`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68585985/8079808

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The answer to this question is ***yes***, this is possible with AWK.

The idea is to keep the header in mind and print all the rest in filenames of the form `filename.00001.csv`:

```
awk -v l=11000 '(NR==1){header=$0;next}
                (NR%l==2) {
                   close(file); 
                   file=sprintf("%s.%0.5d.csv",FILENAME,++c)
                   sub(/csv[.]/,"",file)
                   print header > file
                }
                {print > file}' file.csv
```

This works in the following way:

- **`(NR==1){header=$0;next}`:** If the record/line is the first line, save that line as the *header*.
- **`(NR%l==2){...}`:** Every time we wrote `l=11000` records/lines, we need to start writing to a new file. This happens every time the modulo of the record/line number hits 2. This is on the lines *2, 2+l, 2+2l, 2+3l*,.... When such a line is found we do:

  - **`close(file)`:** close the file you just wrote too.
  - **`file=sprintf("%s.%0.5d.csv",FILENAME,++c); sub(/csv[.]/,"",file)`:** define the new filename as `FILENAME.00XXX.csv`
  - **`print header > file`:** open the file and write the header to that file.
- **`{print > file}`**: write the entries to the file.

**note:** If you don't care about the filename, you can use the following shorter version:

```
awk -v m=100 '
    (NR==1){h=$0;next}
    (NR%m==2) { close(f); f=sprintf("%s.%0.5d",FILENAME,++c); print h > f }
    {print > f}' file.csv
```

Comment: thank you @kvantour this worked very well and pretty fast 5seconds on a file with 1 million rows. much better than my php code :) cheers.

Comment: I am trying to learn more about AWK. I understand variables are dynamic, but how does close(file) not throw an exception as you're trying to close undefined?

Comment: @JonnyWaffles `close()` silently does nothing if given an argument that does not represent a file, pipe, or coprocess that was opened with a redirection. In such a case, it returns a negative value, indicating an error.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I didn't see the silent passing behavior within the docs I found https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/I_002fO-Functions.html. Do you have a particular resource you could recommend for understanding AWK? I am trying to write a similar script that pipes the files to the s3 cli over stdout so I don't write unnecessarily large files to disk, but I don't know how to buffer a logical partition file and call s3 cp - for each one.

Comment: For anyone else who wants to write the output to s3 over stdout it turns out you can simply [pipe](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html#Redirection) to a command, so change `file` to something like `command = "aws s3 cp - s3://bucket/key" c++ ".csv`"

Comment: This is the _best_ awk answer I have ever seen - clearly written, clearly explained, just great. Wish I could give 2 upvotes.

Answer (score 12):

Using GNU `split` to split `file.csv`:

```
export inputPrefix='file' parts=16 && split --verbose -d -n l/${parts} --additional-suffix=.csv --filter='([ "$FILE" != "${inputPrefix}.00.csv" ] && head -1 "${inputPrefix}.csv" ; cat) > "$FILE"' "${inputPrefix}.csv" "${inputPrefix}."
```