# R Looping Large Data

Tags: r

I have a large dataset that I would like to run some code against piece by piece due to its large size for my pc to run in one go.

Here's my code so far...
My dataset has column gene, month, and count

```
df <- read.table(file = "/Users/x/x.txt", 
                         header = TRUE, sep=",", fill=TRUE, comment.char = "")

count_by_gene <- 
  df %>%
  group_by(gene) %>%
  summarize(count = n())
```

I'm unable to import due to the dataset being too large. Is there any way to do this piece by piece and create a different table(count_by_gene) for each piece?

Comment: Does that help you https://rpubs.com/msundar/large_data_analysis?

Comment: if the data set in its entirety is stored locally, perhaps the `disk.frame` package could be useful.

Comment: Sorry, that does not help me. I need to process them piece by piece. I tried setting up a loop and process the data by using nrows and skip. Just can't get the code to work :/

Comment: How large is your data? How many rows vs how many columns?

Comment: about 10gb, and 7 columns

Answer (score 0):

you can try file.split from NCmisc packages

```
library(NCmisc)
orig.dir <- getwd(); setwd(tempdir()); # move to temporary dir
file.name <- "x.txt"
writeLines(fakeLines(max.lines=1000),con=file.name)
new.files <- file.split(file.name,size=50)
unlink(new.files); unlink(file.name)
setwd(orig.dir) # reset working dir to original
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello from what you say you only need to load `gene` column to count by `gene`. For big data frame I would also direct you to `data.table` package that will be more efficient in reading from CSV and processing. If gene names are strings then loading them as `factor` (which are stored as integers) will further reduce memory footprint

```
library(data.table)

# fread is data.table's read.table. It is also smart in detecting
# separators otherwise you can still provide them as parameters
dt <- fread("yourfile.txt", select="gene", stringAsFactors=TRUE)

# here we group by "gene" values and compute for each group the 
# count (using .N pseudo variable)
# the empty comma at the beginning means that we want all lines
count_by_gene <- dt[, by="gene", list(count = .N)]
```

If it is still to big, provided that you can split the file in several chunks using for example hints from [Split CSV files into smaller files but keeping the headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51420966/split-csv-files-into-smaller-files-but-keeping-the-headers) as it seems you are using linux, then you can merge the results with following code

```
file_parts <- c("fic1.txt", "fic2.txt", .... )

# compute counts for each part
parts_counts <- lapply(file_parts, function(file) {
  dt <- fread(file, select="gene", stringAsFactors=TRUE)
  dt[, by="gene", list(count = .N)]
})

# merge part counts in a single table
merged_parts_counts <- rbindlist(parts_counts)

# then total count is sum of part counts
gene_counts <- merged_parts_counts[, by="gene", list(count=sum(count))]
```

It would also be worth having a look at package `hdd` (Easy Manipulation of Out of Memory Data Sets) that looks like what you are looking for.

Comment: This is what I did. The file is still too huge to be able to process it in one go. I also would like to merge this dataframe with a different dataset at some point.

Comment: updated my answer to merge results from different parts